# convert string to date java error "incompatible types"

Tags: java, string, date

I success to get my date from JDateChooser into a string with this line:

```
String d1  = ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
```

I want to know if there is any method to get a date from a JDateChooser ?

I tried to convert this string into a date , and i have an error in the third line .

> "incompatible types : java.util.date cannot be converted to
>   java.sql.Date "

```
    String s = "2011-07-08";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = sdf.parse(s);
```

i have to import the java.util.Date , But i have another error in the same line

> unreported exception ParseException ; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: i have to import the java.util.Date , But i have another error in the same line 

> unreported exception ParseException ; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: The ParseException is a [checked exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions), so you are required to add a Try/Catch exception handler. If you are unaware of this, then you need some study on the basics of Java. Perhaps the [Oracle Tutorial web site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) or [Head First Java](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596009205.do) book from O’Reilly.

Answer (score 3):

You've imported

```
java.sql.Date
```

instead of

```
java.util.Date
```

Change the `import` statement to the appropriate type, ie. `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
String s = "2011-07-08";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(s);
```